# Phonegap 3.3 - not recognize plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Here is my problem with phonegap 3.3.0-0.17.1:

```
my-computer-3411:www giampaolo$ phonegap local plugin list

[phonegap] nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.camera
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.core.camera
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.core.file
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.core.file-transfer
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.device
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.media
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.media-capture
```

phonegap version

```
my-computer-3411:www giampaolo$ phonegap -v
3.3.0-0.17.1
```

When I try to access the camera with this code:

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function (imageURI) {        

            //Remove old data
            localStorage.removeItem('currentPhoto');
            localStorage.removeItem('currentTag');
            localStorage.setItem('currentPhoto', imageURI);
            Backbone.history.navigate('/shot/preview/', {trigger: true});
        },
        function (m) {
            console.log(m);
            alert('some problem');
        },
        {
            quality: 50,
            targetWidth: 600,
            targetHeight: 600,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            correctOrientation: true
        }
    );
```

I got this error (line 14 is console.log):

```
I/Web Console( 1530): Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/controllers/Camera.js:14
```

Any hints/idea?

Is changed something with phonegap 3.3? With phonegap 3.0 it worked well.
Thanks.

Comment: The camera code works fine for me on Cordova/Phonegap 3.3. I think you have your project structure set up incorrectly or something - there isn't a `/www/controllers/` folder in a vanilla Cordova/Phonegap project... that is a Backbone thing. Try removing Backbone from your code to see if it works. Or even just comment out that `Backbone.history.navigate()` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing changed with phonegap 3.3 that should break it. Some troubleshooting steps that may help:

a) Create a hello world application and install a plugin. Confirm it's working.

b) Re-install all plugins. (Remove and Install)

c) Remove all plugins. Delete the [project]/platforms directory. Install plugins, and build again. The [project]/platforms directory will be recreated.

Another Note: Be consistent with your command-line application. Do not mix "phonegap local plugin" with "cordova plugin". I've experienced problems like this doing that in the past.

You can confirm the plugin code is being copied by looking in the [project]/platforms directory under the platform you are compiling for.

Comment: I would like to mention that when I upgraded to 3.3 from 2.9 I had imported `cordova.js` when I should have been importing `phonegap.js` and was getting these errors. I would say look at the project setup of the sample project phonegap builds for you, and check for any discrepancies in your project.